# Transition div when fixed position gets applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code which applies the .stick class to #s-nav when the user scrolls.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
    $('#s-nav').addClass('stick');
    $('#s-nav_placeholder').css({display: 'block'});
  }
  if ($(window).scrollTop() < 300) {
    $('#s-nav').removeClass('stick');
    $('#s-nav_placeholder').css({display: 'none'});
  }
});

});
```

css

```
#s-nav {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.75s ease;
  -moz-transition: top 0.75s ease;
  -ms-transition: top 0.75s ease;
  -o-transition: top 0.75s ease;
  transition: top 0.75s ease;
}

#s-nav_placeholder {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

#s-nav.stick {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

When .stick class gets applied I want it to transition down from the top. The problem is I don't know how to 'start' the div out of screen since It becomes part of the content <300 px from the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this .
modify css to

```
#s-nav.stick {
  position: fixed;
  top: -100%; left: 0; right: 0;
  z-index: 999;       
 -webkit-transition:  0.75s  ;
 -moz-transition:     0.75s  ;
 -ms-transition:      0.75s  ;
 -o-transition:       0.75s  ;
 transition:          0.75s  ;
}
```

then add  `$('#s-nav').css('top','0');` like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
    $('#s-nav').addClass('stick');

    /*new line of code */
    $('#s-nav').css('top','0');

    $('#s-nav_placeholder').css({display: 'block'});
  }
  if ($(window).scrollTop() < 300) {
    $('#s-nav').removeClass('stick');

    /*new line of code */        
    $('#s-nav').css('top','-50%'); 

    $('#s-nav_placeholder').css({display: 'none'});
  }
});

});
```

check this jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/jayakrishnancn/61s0oLLs/1/

Comment: im using firefox 53.0.2 ,working fine. which version r u using? `transition: 0.8s;` might not work for older versions . you should use`-webkit-transition:  0.75s  ;
  -moz-transition:  0.75s  ;
  -ms-transition:  0.75s  ;
  -o-transition:  0.75s  ;
  transition:  0.75s  ;`

Comment: The transition works, the problem is that once I scroll down it works and transitions down as desired. But when I scroll up, It transitions away, but is no longer there with the rest of the content. But it works in Chrome. I have added all the transitions as you mentioned previously. One peculiar thing is that the moment I resize the browser a bit it appears again.

Comment: I just checked with old firefox . still working for me. i think rest of  your code has something to do with this . check if the `#s-nav` has `position:relative` after scrolling back to top. if in case this is set to  `position:absolute` or `fixed` then this might cause the entire  container to move to -100% ie. up (above) screen that is visible. so make sure that #s-nav doesnt have property `position:absolute` or `fixed` (btw .stick  should have position: absolute or fixed  )

Comment: I think you're right. I still give you much thanks for your response